# How to use face unlock in Sony Xperia Z2 running Cyanogemod 12?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, sony-xperia-z2, face-unlock

In Cyanogenmod 12, how do you unlock based on your face? I went to "smart lock" and trained facial recognition. Now I go back to the Screen lock and there is still no option to unlock with the face.

[image: Screenshot with no face unlock option]

<sub>Screenshot - No face unlock option(Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Comment: Under Settings > Security  Ensure that the Smart Lock agent is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set a screen lock with pattern or pin or password
2. Now smart lock will be enabled in Settings->Security below Owner Info
3. In smart lock select trusted face.
4. Lock your phone and you will see a smaller user icon at the bottom.
5. If your face is recognized it will changed to unlock icon. Swipe and it will unlock

Answer (score 1):

Just saw you were running lollipop. Give the above awnser a shot.

You need to reinstall a Gapps package. That isn't the pico or nano 
[image: Gapps chart]
**Step 1**: Here is a link you might want
[Download gapps kitkat](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-_fgPH-TBdZM/VTFfaMwlN7I/AAAAAAAAIjs/WvFEbXOYHNM/s1600/pa_gapps_comparison_chart.png)

**Step 2**: Reboot your phone into the custom recovery (which should already be installed).

**Step 3**: Press install from sdcard and locate the zip.

**Step 4**: Wait for it to install and then reboot the device. And once on it should appear...

If you can't overwrite the Gapps via this method the easiest way to get face unlock would be to get the apk somehow...